# Rails: how to hide order confirmation page (with id in url) from public

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, e-commerce, wicked-pdf

I'm a novice at Rails and am building an e-commerce app. I would appreciate any help at all. My e-commerce app allows for both guest (using sessions for the cart - cart session resets once the order is created) and signed-in users to check out (using devise). Once the order is created, the person who generated the order will be directed to the order show page where they can view details of their order and download a pdf (through wicked_pdf) of the details of their order. However, the issue is that my order show page url references the order id i.e. localhost:3000/orders/[:id], so it's easy for any person who did not make the order to just type in the url to retrieve the order details. If it were just logged in users that could checkout then I could limit the page only to current_user but the issue is when it is a guest checkout.

My solution was to hide the order show page from other users by stating in the show action in the Orders Controller that only if the order is present, then the show page is shown, else redirect to root page. This works for the first rendering of the show page (immediately after the order has been created), but if I click on the pdf on the show page, it no longer detects the order.id and instead redirects to the root page. So although the solution partially works to ensure that anyone who goes to /orders/[:id] gets redirected to the root_path, it also works to direct my pdf requests to the root_path as well.

My Orders controller code is:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

include CurrentCart
before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :create, :show]
before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :destroy]


def new
    if user_signed_in?
        @order = current_user.orders.new
    else
        @order = Order.new
    end
        @client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate
end

def create
    if user_signed_in?
        @order = current_user.orders.new(order_params)
    else
        @order = Order.new(order_params)        
    end
    if @order.save  
        @order.regenerate_auth_token
        charge
        if @result.success? 
        @order[:total_price] = @cart.total_price
        @order.save
        ##Add_carted_activities_from_cart is in cart model - this is what makes the cart go to nil 

            @order.add_carted_activities_from_cart(@cart)   
            Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
            session[:cart_id] = nil
            render :show, notice: 'Thank You for Your Order!'
        else
          flash[:error] = 'Check Your Cart'
          redirect_to new_order_path, alert: @result.message
          @order.destroy
        end
    else
      @client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate
      render :new 
    end
end

def show
    if params.has_key?(:order) 
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.pdf do
            render pdf: "order",
            template: "orders/show.pdf.erb"
          end 
        end 
    else 
        redirect_to root_path       
    end 
end

def destroy
    @order.destroy
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Your Order has been deleted'
end

private

def set_order
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
end


def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:order_status, :activity_quantity, :activity_price, 
            :fees, :taxes, :billing_address, :customer_name, 
            :total_price)
end

def charge
    @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
      amount: @cart.total_price,
      payment_method_nonce: params[:payment_method_nonce])
end
```

end

The other solution I tried (which did not work hence I didn't put the code here) was to use sessions. I set session[:order_id] = @order.id in set_order and defined after_action: destroy_session for :show. Destroy_session was defined as session[:order_id] = nil. This had no effect and anyone could still view the order details by putting in the id in the url.

My Order show page code is

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "cart">
        <div class = "row">
            <h3>Confirm & Pay</h3>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                      <ul class="progressbar">
                            <li>Your Order</li>
                            <li>Confirm & Pay</li>
                            <li class="active">Thank You</li>
                      </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class = "col-md-12">
    <hr>
        <center>
            <div class = "panel panel-default" id = "thankyou">
                <div class = "panel panel-body">
                <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o fa-2x fa-pull-left" aria-hidden="true" style="-webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;"></i>
                    <div class = "thankyou_text">
                        <h5>Thank you, we've received your booking.</h5>
                        <p> 
                            <h6> We will send a confirmation of your booking to <%= @order.customer_email%></h6>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <%= link_to_blank order_path(@order.id, :format => 'pdf') do %> 
            <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #00a8ba;">View Details</i>
            <% end %>
        </center>

        <div class = "summary"> 
        <hr>
            <h5 style = "text-transform: uppercase;">
                Order Number: <%= @order.auth_token.slice(0..4) + @order.id.to_s %> 
            </h5>

            <h5> Summary of your order
            </h5>

            <h6><% @order.carted_activities.each do |carted_activity| %> 

                <p> <%=carted_activity.supplier_activity_option.supplier_activity.activity.name %>
                    x 
                    <%= carted_activity.activity_quantity %>
                    <span class = "right_side"> <%= number_to_currency carted_activity.total_price %> </span>
                </p>
                <% end %> 

                <p>Our Service Fee
                    <span class = "right_side"> Free </span>
                </p>

                <p>Taxes
                    <span class = "right_side">##</span>
                </p>

                <span class = "order_total">
                    <p>Order Total
                        <span class = "right_side"><%=number_to_currency @order.total_price %></span>
                    </p>
                </span>
            </h6>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Route file is

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'place_images/index'

  get 'activity_images/index'

   root to: 'pages#index'

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'users/registrations', omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks"} 
  resources :users

  get 'activities/types' => 'activities#tagged'
  get '/about' => 'pages#about'
  get '/search' => 'searches#search'
  put 'carted_activities/qty' => 'carted_activities#updateQuantity'
  get 'carts/show' => 'carts#show'


  resources :countries 

  resources :regions 

  resources :carted_activities

  resources :carts

  resources :orders

  resources :supplier_activities do
    resources :reviews 
  end

  resources :suppliers

  resources  :activity_images, only:  [:index]
  resources  :place_images, only:  [:index]

  resources :activities, only: [:create, :index, :destroy, :show] do
    resources :wishlists
  end 


end
```

Is there anything else I should be doing to make sure that the pdf requests detects the current order and not get redirected to root_path? Ideally I would need the order show url to be blocked to everyone other than the person who has generated the order BUT the pdf can be viewed AND sent by the person who has generated the order to anyone. Any feedback and guidance on how I can achieve this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: hello.. I did not understand what do you need to do..

Comment: Hi I just need to be able to block public users from being able to see the order show page by accessing order/[:id]. Only the person who has placed the order should get to see the order show page. The issue is that with guest checkout, I can't block public people from seeing the page with check_current_user method.

Answer (score 0):

when ever user load the order show page, check if the order is place by current user or not .

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

before_action :check_current_user, only: [:show]

def check_current_user
 redirect_to root_url unless @order.user == current_user
end
```

Comment: The asker states that he's already doing this. His issue is that guest checkouts don't have an associated user.

Comment: Thanks Aaron and Vishal! Yes as Aaron mentions, the issue is that guest checkouts don't have a current_user so I can't use that before_action.

Comment: @JacintaLim So you dont store any data for guest user ?

Comment: @Vishal, no data stored for guest user. Only when orders are created there will be an order number, customer name, customer email etc that is created for that order.

Comment: @JacintaLim What you store in order number , i mean simple numbers or any random hash ?

Comment: @Vishal simple order.id integer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help. I have now solved this with a sessions hash in my create and show actions in my Orders Controller as follows:

```
def create
        if user_signed_in?
            @order = current_user.orders.new(order_params)
        else
            @order = Order.new(order_params)        
        end
        if @order.save  
            @order.regenerate_auth_token
            charge
            if @result.success? 
            @order[:total_price] = @cart.total_price
            @order.save
            session[:order] = true
            ##Add_carted_activities_from_cart is in cart model - this is what makes the cart go to nil 
                @order.add_carted_activities_from_cart(@cart)   
                Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
                session[:cart_id] = nil
                render :show, notice: 'Thank You for Your Order!'
            else
              flash[:error] = 'Check Your Cart'
              redirect_to new_order_path, alert: @result.message
              @order.destroy
            end
        else
          @client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate
          render :new 
        end
    end

    def show
        if !session[:order].blank?
            respond_to do |format|
              format.html
              format.pdf do
                render pdf: "seeksophie_order",
                template: "orders/show.pdf.erb"
              end 
            end 
            session.delete(:order)
        else 
            redirect_to root_path       
        end 
    end
```